# Looking around with your eyes without moving your head

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

Is there a word or phrase for looking just by moving your eyeballs?

Something like: "the way the helmet was attached to the armour prevented her from turning her head to look at him. Instead, she looked around with her eyes and caught a glimpse of him out of the corner."

Comment: Although I like *"She rolled her eyes around the room"*.  I have to concede that it doesn't quite achieve figurative lift off!

Comment: May be [Smooth pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_pursuit)  or [Saccade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade) or just pupillary movement?

Comment: 'She looked' is all that is needed. 'Looking' and 'seeing' both imply eye movement and peripheral vision within the scope of their meaning. _Despite the restrictions of the helmet, she looked and could see etc etc_

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (but asking for a noun instead of a verb): [What is the word that means "looking at something without moving the head, just eyeballs."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428036/what-is-the-word-that-means-looking-at-something-without-moving-the-head-just)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*They swivelled their eyes towards X* imparts the meaning you want, that the movement of the eyes happens independent of the head.

[Swivel-eyed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/swivel-eyed) refers to someone who is *constantly* swivelling their eyes, implying frenzy.
However *they swivelled their eyes* will be understood as a one-off occurence.

If they have not found what they're looking for, you may use sweep or swept as in:

*Their gaze swept the horizon for pirate ships*

Swept [implies a swift, broad and lofty movement](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweep) which is much more suited to the movement of the eyes than the rest of the body.

Comment: Nice! I love *swiveling her eyes*, it captures the feeling of isolated eye movement.

Answer (score 0):

> "the way the helmet was attached to the armour prevented her from
>   turning her head to look at him. Instead, **she looked** around **with her**
>   **eyes** and caught a glimpse of him out of the corner."

"she looked with her eyes" is of course a pleonasm so I suggest avoiding that.

Almost any verb implying movement should do, e.g.

*"the way the helmet was attached to the armour prevented her from turning her head to look at him. Instead, she moved her eyes and caught a glimpse of him out of the corner."*

I don't think it's necessary but if you really want to emphasise it, try the following:

*"the way the helmet was attached to the armour prevented her from turning her head to look at him. Instead, she moved just her eyes and caught a glimpse of him out of the corner."*

Answer (score 0):

I would say “[out of the corner of one’s eye](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/out-of-the-corner-of-one-s-eye#:%7E:text=Glancing%20casually%20or%20surreptitiously%2C%20as,at%20something%20rather%20than%20directly.).”

For example,

> The way the helmet was attached to the armour prevented her from turning her head to look at him. Still, out of the corner of her eye she caught a glimpse of him standing in the corner.